# checking if login it and cart is empty

Tags: php

I am trying to combine two IF statements.

the `FIRST` statement checks if the cart if empty.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)
```

The `SECOND` statement change if the user is login in or not...

```
 if ($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null)
```

I need to check if the cart is empty and if it is I have echo a message saying. `cart if empty` at the same thing i need to change if the user is login and if they is i dont want to show a form which I have and if they are not, they form should show.

**I tried this** *but didn't work*

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    echo 'cart if emepy';
    if ($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null) {           
    }
}
else{
   echo ' <form name="login" action="login.php"></form>';
}
```

**summary**
The first statement checks if they is anything in cart and if they is nothing, the form should not show. IF the user is logged in the form should not show if they is anything in the cart because the form is a login in form and they is no point for the person to log in twice... The second if statement is statement that i used to check if someone is logged in or not

Comment: Try using `&&` instead of `||`, see if that works for you. As in `if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {` - you're only checking if one or the other matches the criteria. `&&` checks for both.

Comment: @Fred I did, it didn't work... the form still shows even when I am login, when it shouldn't...

Comment: the form shouldn't show when someone is login and when the cart it cart. if the cart has something instead of it the cart should show. If someone already login in and doesn't have anything in the cart and then add something. The form shouldn't show

Comment: Ok. Try one of the answers below then.

Comment: so what is supposed to happen when the user is not logged in?

Comment: @koala_dev if the user is not logged in the form will show so that the can log in...

if u do only shopping and when u click on the cart link and you have nothing in the cart all you see if a message tell you that the cart is empty... if you have something inside and you are not `LOGGED` in you get an option below the items, telling you to log in.

Comment: check Perry's updated answer, I think he got it right

Comment: @koala_dev sadly it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs to be something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
echo 'cart if emepy';
} else {

if (is_null($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl']) || !isset($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'])) {
echo ' <form name="login" action="login.php">

</form>';

} else {

}
}
```

The problem was that your check for the user was in the check if the cart wat empty or not.

Comment: why are u empying the session cart?

Comment: Sorry mistake that is not needed, I will remove it. Did it help to resolve your problem?

Comment: sorry still nothing... when I am log out and nothing is in the cart, it shows the empty message if I have something in the cart while I am still log off the form doesn't show...

Comment: I changed my answer. The form had to be in the if statement not in the else.

Comment: your code doesn't work... I will explain my question again.

The first statement checks if they is anything in cart and if they is nothing, the form should not show. IF the user is logged in the form should not show if they is anything in the cart because the form is a login in form and they is no point for the person to log in twice...

The second if statement is statement that i used to check if someone is logged in or not

Comment: In summary, the form should only show if the person is not log in and when something is in the cart. If someone is logged in already the form should not show

Comment: Edited my answer again

Comment: when i am logged in the form doesn't show

Comment: That is your question right? When the person is not loggedin then login else no login form...

Comment: if i am not logged in and have something in the cart. The form doesn't show, its the same thing is it is empty. IT is might to show if i have something in the cart and I am not logged in

Comment: Can you do a var dump on your session and check what value is set for the `$_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl']`

Comment: that is that to check if the user is logged in or not and also what accesslvl they have in they account weather they are admin or just standard users

Comment: I edited my answer this should work now

Comment: the form doesn't show... when i have something in the cart and I am not logged it

Comment: @SarahJames I tried the code my self and it works. Can you show me the code you are using now by updating your question?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't try to do something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1 && $_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] != null)
{
    echo "logged in but cart empty";
}
else if($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null)
{
   echo "not logged in";
}
else
    echo "all right, logged in and cart not empty!";
```

Comment: this didn't work either

Comment: @SarahJames Check now, there were some syntax errors. I edited the code.

Comment: Do you get some kind of error? Or do you always get a particular echo?

Comment: no error, your code works how it shouldn't but it doesn't do what I want it to do... I think I might need to duplicate the form for each statements thats is needed

Comment: you mean that you want to show the login form when the user is logged in?

Comment: wouldn't that be pointless to show a login form when you are already logged in?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I mean show the form when the user si not logged in.

Comment: yes, if you are not logged in the show will show and if the cart is empty the form will still not show... the form will only show if  u r not logged in

Comment: I think my code is right. Replace the echo not logged in with the echo of the form , and the last echo with the parte that will show the items in the cart.

Comment: I have 2 unanswered questions. if you have time for them. Thanks

Comment: you code doesn't fully work... if i am not loggged in and they is nothing inthe cart it still shows

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)
{
    echo "cart is empty";
}
else
{
    //show cart here
    if ($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null) //user is not logged in
    {
        //show login form
        echo ' <form name="login" action="login.php"></form>';
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for trying koala... i dont think anyone understand, what I mean

Comment: are you sure your login check is correct? So you have 4 cases: #1 cart is empty and user logged in, #2 cart is empty user NOT logged in, #3 cart has items and user is logged in, #4 cart has items and user is not logged in. So for #1 we show 'cart is empty', for #2 we show "empty" and form, #3 we show cart, #4 we show cart and form. That's how my answer works

Comment: i notice thats how it works but i didn't think you understood my question but doesn't matter, cris answered it. Thanks for your help and time :) x