# Validation two things with IF statement

Tags: php

Sorry I couldn't find a better topic for this topic.

I have a cart page and I am changing for two things... The code I am about to show you works but I want to combine them.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)
```

The code above check if the cart is empty

```
if ($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null) { *this code check if the user is logged in or not.*
```

**My question**
I have a `form` and I want to show this form on the page **only** when the cart is **not** empty. `If` is the cart is empty the form shouldn't show.
**also** if the user is already sign in, the form `shouldn't` show.

```
echo ' <form name="login" action="login.php">

</form>';
```

**I tired this**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
} else {

if ($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null) {
echo ' <form name="login" action="login.php">

</form>';

} else {

}
}
```

**Summary**
`SHOULD ONLY, if user is NOT logged in`
The form should only show when they is something(item) in the cart `and` if the user is `NOT` logged it.

`SHOULD NOT`
If the user is logged in already, the form should not show because they is no point asking someone to log in twice.

Can someone help me please. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't ask a new question, you should update your [last one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17912066/2049063), once again I believe you can be more clear on your description, from what you wrote here I gather you just need to show the form when the user is not logged in and the cart is not empty, that should be simple enough

Comment: @koala_dev "simple enough" sounds easy but its not so easy for me. Why don't you post your easy answer please

Comment: Before I do, I need to be sure that that's in fact what you need. So the only condition when the form should display is when there's items in the cart and the user is not logged in?

Comment: @koala_dev yes that is one of the conditions. The form shouldn't show if the user is logged in already and also if the logged in user cart is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
if (!(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) && $_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null) {
    echo ' <form name="login" action="login.php"></form>';
} else {
    ...
}
```

The following is just the explanation of the if-condition. This is **NO** valid syntax:

If the card is not empty > `!(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)` AND  the user is not logged in > `$_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null` it shows the form.

Comment: this doesn't work. even when I have something in the cart and I am `NOT` logged in, the form is might to show.

Comment: @Sarah actually the form won't show whenever the user is logged in as you asked

Comment: I changed the code. So when the cart is empty or the user is not logged in, it shows the form. 
@koala_dev: When the user is logged in, the form should not show at all. That is the desired result she asked for.

Comment: but it should show when the user is NOT logged in and the cart is not empty

Comment: @SarahJames: I changed my code again back to the first suggestion. If the card is NOT empty AND the user is NOT logged in it shows the form. If the user is logged in or the card is empty the form will not be displayed.

Comment: the first or second code? if its the second one please arrange it

Comment: @SarahJames: What do you mean? THe code example in my answer. The part after that is just an explanation.

Comment: "`If the card is not empty > !(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) AND the user is not logged in > $_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null it shows the form.`" what is this?

Comment: Like i said this is just the previous code example explained a little bit more. This is **NO** valid syntax so use the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The first condition:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)
```

Can be shortened to simply this:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['cart_array']))
```

Because `count()` only returns a value less than 1 if the array is empty. Furthermore, `empty()` also behaves like `isset()` internally.

Then, you can simply add the other condition like this:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['cart_array']) && !isset($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'])) {
    // show form
}
```

The `isset()` doesn't raise a notice when trying to access `$_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl']` if it doesn't exist.

**Update**

To make this whole thing easier to maintain you could introduce some helper functions, e.g.:

```
function isCartEmpty()
{
    return empty($_SESSION['cart_array']);
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl']);
}

if (!isCartEmpty() && !isLoggedIn()) {
    // show form
}
```

Comment: @SarahJames I've updated the answer to make the code more readable (and maintainable) :)

Comment: thanks jack, I will use this but i cant give u the answer because someone else already answered it but i will vote for it. :D thanks again xxx

Comment: @SarahJames Not saying that you should, but you can change the accepted answer actually :)

Comment: lol, you can post this answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912066/checking-if-login-it-and-cart-is-empty?lq=1) i will vote for you :D

Comment: @SarahJames Actually, since that question is almost the same as this you should delete the older question.

Comment: I have another question which needs an answer. I know you will be able to answer it, and example it, do you have time or should i post it later?

Comment: please [the question i was talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921321/how-to-encrypt-product-id-in-url)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so in essence ther are two things you want to check in your condition, that is we have two variables:

Variable 1: cart is empty

Variable 2: user is logged in

So we have 4 possibilities of events that can happen when someone visits your page:

1. cart is empty AND user IS logged in
2. cart is empty AND user is NOT logged in
3. cart is NOT empty AND user IS logged in
4. cart is NOT empty AND user is NOT logged in

Now this is your last comment regarding the conditions on which you want the form to show:

"The form shouldn't show if the user is logged in already and also if the logged in user cart is empty"

So in the first part you don't want the form when the user is logged in, that means options 1 and 3 above should NOT display the form (we are left with 2 and 4), then you say you don't want the form when the cart is empty, that means option 2 is a no no and we are left with option 4, that's when you do want the form to show:

**You want the form when: Cart is NOT empty AND user is NOT logged in**

Translated to code:

Cart is NOT empty:

`!(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)`

User is NOT logged in:

`$_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null`

Combine with AND and you get

```
if (!(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) && $_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null) {
    echo ' <form name="login" action="login.php"></form>';
} else {
    ...
}
```

just as @TobiasKun posted in his answer

Comment: so far as I understand the question she only want view the form when the cart is not empty and the user is not logged in.

Comment: Then the problem is not in the logic but in how the conditions are being tested. Try with @Jack's answer and tell us how it isn't working, is it displaying the form when you don't want to or not displaying when you want to.